# BadToken exception even if activity is running

Tags: android, exception

I am getting this exception while trying to display a dialog in android.  I found in some posts that i must check the value of

```
isFinishing()
```

to check whether an activity is going to finish.  But I always get the value as "false" from this function.

Which means that activity is running.  But i still getting the exception

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window
```

Can any body help me to solve this.

Here is my code

```
  final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ThirdTab.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alertview);
    dialog.setTitle("text");

    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);

    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
       {                    
      dialog.dismiss();
       }
    }
   );
     runOnUiThread
        (
           new Runnable() 
           {

        @Override
        public void run() 
                {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(!ThirdTab.this.isFinishing())
            {
               dialog.show();
            }
        }
        }  
        );
```

Comment: Post the code you are using to display the Dialog.

Comment: as you are checking for the is finishing in the thread. it might be possible that as the thread runs it keeps n giving false

Comment: @krishna what i need to change

Comment: @DavidWasser check my edit to the post

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.  This happens because my activity is inside a tab activity.  That is why the function `isFinishing()` returns false and the Exception occurs.

I thank you all who responded to this question.